# WPS VS Access Point when connecting to WiFi

Tags: security, user-interface, wifi, esp8266

I'm building a commercial esp8266 device. I need it to connect to WiFi to use the device with an app.
I managed to connect it via both WPS and Access Point (getting the SSID and Password from the app by connecting to the Access Point). 
I'm trying to understand which of these two would be ideal for commercial use.
WPS compromises network security until a device connects but it is super fast.
AP doesn't compromise security but it is slower + the user loses his WiFi connection until he passes the SSID and Password.
Another problem is that people might not be able to find the WPS button on their router.

Which of these two methods of connecting to WiFi should I use? 
So, essentially what should I choose between Speed and Security?

Edit: It's important to note that multiple commercial devices use WPS to connect (printers for example).

Answer (score 1):

In a commercial setting using WPS makes no sense at all, just use the access point information as you do not want to have any chance of security breach.